# CCDC algorithm in Google Earth Engine: "Description length exceed maximum" error when trying to visualize first segment classification

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to run the CCDC algorithm in GEE JavaScript API, but I am getting a `Description length exceeds maximum` error after classifying the segments and trying to visualize the first segment classification. I am following [the official tutorial](https://gee-ccdc-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lctut.html).

Link to my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b30dbe56464060d0162bc27c8100e072

```
// Imports
var geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* shown: false */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-102.1292783057271, 19.661469047050613],
          [-102.1292783057271, 19.302847913323443],
          [-101.62116062994585, 19.302847913323443],
          [-101.62116062994585, 19.661469047050613]]], null, false),
    bosque1 = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-102.09960329763422, 19.422619532783482],
          [-102.09961402647028, 19.42744587759881],
          [-102.10513937704096, 19.427476231515012],
          [-102.10513937704096, 19.422619532783482]]]),
    agua1 = /* color: #0b4a8b */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-101.64643930467143, 19.62567959667342],
          [-101.64643930467143, 19.643302736805417],
          [-101.62978815110698, 19.643302736805417],
          [-101.62978815110698, 19.62567959667342]]]),
    noBosque1 = /* color: #00ffff */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-101.98808341292984, 19.580129025462814],
          [-101.98808341292984, 19.585668348503933],
          [-101.98087363509781, 19.585668348503933],
          [-101.98087363509781, 19.580129025462814]]]),
    urbano = 
    /* color: #c5c5c5 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-102.06348521242772, 19.424106929778997],
          [-102.06348521242772, 19.41374558218085],
          [-102.05232722292577, 19.41374558218085],
          [-102.05232722292577, 19.424106929778997]]], null, false);

// CCDC
var utils = require('users/parevalo_bu/gee-ccdc-tools:ccdcUtilities/api')
// Define parameters

// Change detection parameters
var changeDetection = {
  breakpointBands: ['BLUE', 'GREEN','RED','NIR','SWIR1','SWIR2'],
  tmaskBands: ['GREEN','SWIR2'],
  minObservations: 6,
  chiSquareProbability: .99,
  minNumOfYearsScaler: 1.33,
  dateFormat: 2,
  lambda: 20/10000,
  maxIterations: 25000
};

// Classification parameters
var classification = {
  bandNames: ["BLUE","GREEN","RED","NIR","SWIR1","SWIR2"],
  inputFeatures: ["INTP", "SLP","PHASE","RMSE"],
  coefs: ["INTP", "SLP","COS", "SIN","RMSE","COS2","SIN2","COS3","SIN3"],
  ancillaryFeatures: ["ELEVATION","ASPECT","DEM_SLOPE","RAINFALL","TEMPERATURE"],
  resultFormat: 'SegCollection',
  classProperty: 'LC_Class',
  yearProperty: 'year',
  classifier: ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest,
  classifierParams: {
    numberOfTrees: 150,
    variablesPerSplit: null,
    minLeafPopulation: 1,
    bagFraction: 0.5,
    maxNodes: null
  },
  outPath: 'CCDC_Mich',
  segs: ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6"],
  };

var studyRegion = geometry;

var params = {
  start: '2000-01-01',
  end: '2020-01-01',
  ChangeDetection: changeDetection,
  Classification: classification,
  StudyRegion: studyRegion
}

// Filter by date and a location 
var filteredLandsat = utils.Inputs.getLandsat()
    .filterBounds(params.StudyRegion)
    .filterDate(params.start, params.end)

print('filteredLandsat',filteredLandsat.size());

params.ChangeDetection['collection'] = filteredLandsat

var ccdcResults = ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.Ccdc(params.ChangeDetection)
print(ccdcResults)

// Definición de colección de vectores
var poligonos = ee.FeatureCollection([
    ee.Feature(noBosque1, {'LC_Class': 0}),
    ee.Feature(bosque1, {'LC_Class': 1}),
    ee.Feature(agua1, {'LC_Class': 2}),
    ee.Feature(urbano, {'LC_Class': 3}),
]);

var trainingData = poligonos;
trainingData  = trainingData.map(function(feat) {
    return feat.set('year',2015)});
print('training data first', trainingData.limit(10));

// Define bands to use in classification
var bands = params.Classification.bandNames

// Define coefficients to use in classification
var coefs = params.Classification.coefs

// Segment ids
var segs = params.Classification.segs

// Property corresponding to year of training data
var yearProperty = params.Classification.yearProperty

// Define path to change detection results
params.Classification.changeResults = ccdcResults;

// Load ccd image stack with coefficients and change information
var ccdImage = utils.CCDC.buildCcdImage(params.Classification.changeResults, params.Classification.segs.length, params.Classification.bandNames)

print('CCD Image:', ccdImage)

// Finally, get ancillary topographic and climate data
var ancillary = utils.Inputs.getAncillary()

var trainingData = utils.Classification.getTrainingCoefsAtDate(
  trainingData, coefs, bands, yearProperty, ancillary, ccdImage, segs)

// Filter points with no data
var testBand = params.Classification.bandNames[0] + '_' + params.Classification.coefs[0]
trainingData = trainingData.filter(ee.Filter.notNull([testBand]))

print('First training point with predictors:', trainingData.first())

Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: trainingData,
  description: 'trainingDataProcessed',
  assetId: params.Classification.trainingPathPredictors});
  
trainingData = utils.Classification.assignIds(trainingData, 'ID');

// Now do the actual classification add the first segments classification to the map

// Optionally filter by study area
trainingData = trainingData.filterBounds(params.StudyRegion)

// Next, turn array image into image
var imageToClassify = utils.CCDC.buildCcdImage(params.Classification.changeResults, params.Classification.segs.length, params.Classification.bandNames)

// Now get ancillary data
var demImage = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003').rename('ELEVATION')
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(demImage).rename('DEM_SLOPE')
var aspect = ee.Terrain.aspect(demImage).rename('ASPECT')
var bio = ee.Image('WORLDCLIM/V1/BIO')
    .select(['bio01','bio12'])
    .rename(['TEMPERATURE','RAINFALL'])
var ancillary = ee.Image.cat([demImage, slope, aspect, bio])

// Get classifier with params
var classifier = params.Classification.classifier(params.Classification.classifierParams)
print('params', params);
var results = utils.Classification.classifySegments(
    imageToClassify, 
    params.Classification.segs.length, 
    params.Classification.bandNames,
    ancillary, 
    params.Classification.ancillaryFeatures,
    trainingData, 
    classifier, 
    params.StudyRegion, 
    params.Classification.classProperty,
    params.Classification.inputFeatures)
    .clip(params.StudyRegion);

Map.addLayer(results.select(0).randomVisualizer(), {}, 'Seg1 Classification')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several tests, I found that the error is only implying that the computation time required to show the image exceeds the user's limit. Thus, you can simply export the image and obtain the desired output. Usually, this is an intermediate step in the CCDC workflow, so a solution is exporting it to an asset.

```
Export.image.toAsset({
  image:results,
    description: 'SegmentsClassification',
    region: studyRegion,
    pyramidingPolicy: {
    ".default": 'sample'
    },
    crs: 'EPSG:6362',
    scale: 30
});
```